# Does the complex exponential function $\exp(z)$ have an axiomatic definition?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, eulers-number-e

It is known that the real exponential function $e^{(\cdot)}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can be characterized as the unique real function satisfying these three properties:

1. $e^{1}=e$, where $e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$.
2. $e^{x+y}=e^{x}e^{y}$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
3. For some real number $x_0$, $e^{(\cdot)}$ is continuous at $x_0$, that is $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}e^{x}=e^{x_0}$

The complex exponential function $e^{(\cdot)}:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is usually defined by $e^{z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$. I'm wondering if it can be characterized using axioms analogous to the ones above.

**Context**: Lately, I've been wondering whether the identity $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ is as "beautiful" or "remarkable" as people often make it out to be. To me, it seems like it is not a fascinating result so much as a consequence of the definition

$$e^{z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

and the series expansions of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Nonetheless, I often hear people saying things like "$e^{i\pi}+1=0$ relates the constants $e$, $\pi$, $i$, $1$ and $0$", leading me to wonder if there's a deeper connection I have not discovered yet. Reflecting on these thoughts, I realized that $e^z$ having an axiomatic characterization lends credence to the idea that $e$ is special in relation to the identity $e^{i\pi}+1=0$, precisely because it is the **only** number satisfying <insert property 1 analogue here>.

I apologize if my context is unclear. If you need clarification or have useful edits, please feel free to leave a comment or edit my post.

Comment: Does $e^z=\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+z/n)^n$ count?

Comment: what about the unique complex differentiable function satisfying $f'=f, f(0)=1$; given that, one can prove the group property, the fact that $f(i \mathbb R)=\mathbb S^1$, construct $\pi, \sin, \cos$ their geometric properties (eg circle parameterization, area, circumference etc) and so on; showed this recently in a post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848284/proving-that-these-definitions-of-pi-are-equivalent-area-and-half-circumfere/3848306#3848306

Comment: More than that, $e^{i\times\pi}+1=0$ uses each of$$0,\,1,\,e,\,\pi,\,i,\,+,\,\times,\,\underbrace{((a,\,b)\mapsto a^b)}_\text{Hard to denote},\,=$$once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $\exp\colon\Bbb C\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is the only holomorphic function from $\Bbb C$ into $\Bbb C$ for which those three conditions hold. So, it's the same axiomatic description.

Or you can say that it is the only function from $\Bbb C$ into $\Bbb C$ which maps $1$ into $e$, which maps sums into products and which is differentiable at some point of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Really? It's quite surprising that the exact same conditions carry over to $\mathbb{C}$!

Comment: @A. E.: is it? The Taylor series is the same, after all. There’s a reason we call them both the exponential function.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan complex analytic functions often exhibit behavior not shown by their real analytic counterparts, so I was expecting stronger conditions.

Comment: @A.E.: Yes, but practically all of that behavior is about *rigidity*; e.g. a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ is determined by its restriction to $\mathbb{R}$, and in fact by its restriction to an infinite subset of $\mathbb{C}$ with a limit point. It's easy to pin down holomorphic functions!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I didn't know holomorphic functions can be completely determined by their values on $\mathbb{R}$! That's really cool!

Comment: @A.E.: this is the identity theorem, and it may give some intuitive sense of why e.g. results like the Cauchy integral formula could possibly be true: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: ..by the values on $\mathbb R$ , as well as by the values on the unit circumference in $\mathbb C$, etc.

Answer (score 14):

There are a few things I say over and over again on math.SE, and one of them is that the cleanest definition of the exponential function (on either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, or more generally even) is that it's the unique function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$) satisfying

- $f(0) = 1$, and
- $f'(x) = f(x)$.

Note that this definition makes no explicit reference to $e$. Every other property of the exponential function falls easily out of this definition together with the existence and uniqueness theorems for solutions to ODEs. For example, by the chain rule

$$\frac{d}{dz} \exp(z + w) = \exp(z + w)$$

hence $\exp(z + w)$ is also a solution to the above ODE but with initial condition $\exp(w)$. But so is $\exp(z) \exp(w)$. Hence the two are equal by the uniqueness theorem.

Similarly we get continuity at every point and the usual power series expansion. The limit

$$\exp(z) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{n} \right)^n$$

then falls out of applying the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) with step size $\frac{z}{n}$ to approximate solutions to this ODE. (It can also be formally justified by differentiating with respect to $z$ but this requires some thought about exchanging the derivative and the limit.)

This allows us to give a clean definition of $e$ as just being the value $\exp(1)$ (another thing I say over and over again on math.SE is that $e$ is not important, $\exp(z)$ is important and $e$ just happens to be its value at $z = 1$), and a clean definition of $\pi$: with $\exp(z)$ defined as above, $\pi$ is the smallest positive real such that $\exp(2 \pi i) = 1$, or in other words it's half the period of $\exp(it)$. Note that by the chain rule

$$\frac{d}{dt} \exp(it) = i \exp(it)$$

so $\exp(it)$ is a solution to the ODE $f(0) = 1, f'(t) = i f(t)$ for a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$. But $\cos t + i \sin t$ is also such a solution. So by the uniqueness theorem we recover [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

$$\exp(it) = \cos t + i \sin t.$$

This requires that we know what the trigonometric functions are in advance, but we can actually invent them this way instead. Additivity gives $\exp(it) \exp(-it) = \exp(0) = 1$, but we also have

$$\frac{d}{dt} \exp(it) \overline{\exp(it)} = 0$$

from which it follows that $\exp(-it) = \overline{\exp(it)}$ and that $\| \exp(it) \| = 1$ is a constant. So $\exp(it) = c(t) + i s(t)$ satisfies

$$c(t)^2 + s(t)^2 = 1$$
$$c(-t) = c(t), s(-t) = - s(t)$$
$$c(t_1 + t_2) = c(t_1) c(t_2) - s(t_1) s(t_2)$$
$$s(t_1 + t_2) = c(t_1) s(t_2) + s(t_1) c(t_2)$$

and we're well on our way to rediscovering trigonometry. These identities can be used to show that $\exp(it)$ is periodic by showing that it not only lies on the unit circle but travels on it with constant velocity (this basically follows from additivity).

The same uniqueness idea applied to the trigonometric functions tells us that $(\cos t, \sin t)$ is the unique pair of functions satisfying

- $c(0) = 1, s(0) = 0$, and
- $c'(t) = -s(t), s'(t) = c(t).$

Every other trigonometric identity is a consequence of these. This one may be a little less intuitive but it says that the vector $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} c'(t) \\ s'(t) \end{array} \right]$ is a $90^{\circ}$ rotation of, and in particular orthogonal to, the vector $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} c(t) \\ s(t) \end{array} \right]$, which e.g. after differentiating a second time, exactly describes a particle under the influence of a constant centripetal force.

Comment: Hey Qiaochu, thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I may be missing a key point you're trying to make here, but this feels like a top-down approach. Why would you want to define $\pi$ like that? Sure, this definition is equivalent to its usual geometric/trigonometric definition, but it definitely does not seem reasonable. On top of that, defining $\sin$ and $\cos$ using $\exp$ as you did seems to miss what I'm seeking. It seems like these definitions render $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ as a trivial consequence rather than a surprising result, and I **want** to see the identity in the latter way.

Comment: @A.E.: it's mostly just fun to see that it's possible. I like results that tell me that certain mathematical objects are "inevitable" - you'd be forced to write them down for many general reasons - and this is one of my favorite ones of those. Of course you don't have to take this as a definition of the trigonometric functions; the point is that once you've shown in any way that $\frac{d}{dt} \cos t = -\sin t$ and $\frac{d}{dt} \sin t = \cos t$ then Euler's formula and $e^{i \pi} = -1$ fall out immediately. The conceptual content is that $\exp(it)$ describes a rotation by $t$ radians.

Comment: @A.E.: but maybe I have misunderstood your motivating question. Can you say more about it?

Comment: Excellent...ex-student :-)..:-)

Answer (score 0):

Bourbaki's definition is that it is the sum of the series
$$\exp(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$
It has an infinite radius of convergence and thus  is a holomorphic function defined on $\mathbf C$.

The functions $\sin z , \cos z$ and $\sinh z,\cosh z$ are similarly by power series.